# Attempting to dismiss keyboard with "return" button

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a To Do List app, and I am want to make it so when the user presses "return" when typing the keyboard would close and disappear. I thought I wrote the function correctly, but it isn't working. The bit of code I am asking about it toward the end.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var addLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet var enteredItem: UITextField!


    @IBAction func addItemButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        toDoList.append(enteredItem.text)

        enteredItem.text = ""

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(toDoList, forKey: "toDoList")

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        self.view.endEditing(true)

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you set the textField's delegate to be this viewController? If you put a breakpoint in `textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool` do you ever hit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things missed

- SecondViewController must implements `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

- You have to set text field delegate to `self`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.enteredItem.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still a beginner and I need to get good at the process. Wasn't aware that you had to take those two steps.